# location.href in Firefox

Tags: jquery, ajax, firefox

In my jQuery Ajax script, I wrote

```
$.ajax({
            url: SearchUrl,
            type: 'POST',
            data: submitData,
            dataType: 'json',
success: function (rec) {
                if (rec.data) {
                    if (rec.data.url) {
                        pageLoading();
                        location.href = rec.data.url;
                    }
                    if (rec.data.error) {
                        errorText.text(rec.data.error);
                    }
                }
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                location.href = refreshUrl;
            }
        });
```

The thing is that there does have rec.data.url in the return data from the controller. The code works well to redirect to the url given in rec.data.url when I tested on IE, Safari, Chrome.However this didn't work in Firefox 10.1, only the current page is reloaded but not any redirection.
if I put an alert("") between pageLoading() and location.href = rec.data.url, Firefox will redirect to the url in rec.data.url after the alert message.

Comment: That's interesting, it almost sounds like it is calling the code asynchronously. You are using the success callback properly and that should not be happening.

Comment: @mrtsherman what do you mean by "should not be happening"? if I add the alert, the success does work as what I want it to work.

Comment: The alert is symptomatic of a problem. The reason the alert 'fixes' the problem is because it gives the call time to finish. If you added `async: false` or called your location change in a `setTimeout` it may also 'fix' it. I don't see how this could happen. If you can post a fiddle where this occurs it would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
window.location = 'your url';
```

somehow I guess in FF and few other browsers `window.location.href` is readonly property, thus it fails but just using location should be ok

Comment: Is this different from location.href?

Comment: no really much different for a give question because these has been implemented a while ago since may be Netscape days but for few browsers around `href` could only be readonly property and thus may not give you results you want. I could be wrong but I am pretty sure that many months back I have to come across this.